# How to align paragraph verticaly and horizontaly like MS word using Openxml?

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I would like to align paragraph that i am passing as table to word document using open xml as 
vertically and horizonaly like as MS word does.

[image]
how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by my own with use of ParagraphProperties and TablecellProperties of openxml wordprocessing class.
To align Vertically, I have used TablecellProperties  to vertically align and ParagraphProperties  to horizonal align and TextRotation.